# Netbeans needs Tomcat Password Eclipse doesnt

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, netbeans

I have Eclipse and Netbeans and I am running Tomcat. I can't start Tomcat in Netbeans without  a password, but I can in Eclipse. I don't have a username or password set in tomcat-users.xml and eclipse works fine. Why cant I do that with Netbeans.

Comment: have you set correct catalina base in netbeans?

Comment: yes, exactly the same. Triple checked.

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, but Eclipse does by default not take control over the Tomcat installation, but just uses its sole engine and deploys the webapps into workspace metadata. That might have made difference. Try changing the *Server Locations* setting in Eclipse to see if it would now also ask for the password.